# How to make <div> 1:1 ratio in size?

Tags: html

height but the width always has to be fixed and so would the height, so that did not work.

`img` inside to take up the full width of it, and for the height be :9 of it, and continue to maintain the even if the fluid `div` changes.

**PS:** I need pure CSS based answers if possible.

Comment: if your image is already in the ratio that you mentioned, then, only changing width of img will automatically adjust height if height is auto(default)

Comment: @KiranShakya The images themselves have all difference sizes, but each `<div/>` the each image contains in are of same size. So how can I have the `<img/>` fill the full width of the `<div/>` and keep 16:9 size for the `<img/>` as well, despite how tall the `<div/>` is?

Answer (score 2):

If your div has the height and width in 16:9 aspect ratio, then all you have to do is:

```js
$('.container').height($(this).width()*9/16);
$( window ).resize(function() { $('.container').height($(this).width()*9/16); });
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

- Setting `position: relative;` informs the browser to manipulate children relative to the div.
- Setting height and width to 100% will stretch the image to fit the div.
- About object-fit: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#object-fit
- If you want the image to be cropped to fit the div, then `object-fit: cover;` will be useful.
- If stretching is not a problem, then you don't need object-position and object-fit properties at all.

Comment: I don't know the `div`'s size because it is fluid. But whatever the width of the `div` is, I would like the `img` inside to take up the full width of it, and for the height be :9 of it, and continue to maintain the 16:9 even if the fluid `div` changes.

Comment: if you expect answer as pure css based, then why you include javascript tag in your OP? Your question doesn't relate to javascript in that sense. Besides, there may be some pure css methods but unfortunately I don't have any on my sleeves right now.

Comment: Did I include jQuery tag in my OP though?

Comment: You had included Javascript in your Question, which now have been removed to suit your request. FYI jQuery is a js library.

Answer (score 0):

```
img{
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: How can I make the fluid container of the `img` a 16:9 ratio in size  so that setting `img` to 100% would keep the `img` 16:9 ratio in size as well in relation to the fluid container's size?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the width of the div, because it's fluid. You can use the `padding-bottom` property to give the element height relative to the width:

```css
.container {
   width: 100%;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   position: relative;
   background: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Then you can absolutely position the image inside the center of the container;

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  background: black;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;   
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Edit:

The `position:absolute` will pull the img out of the flow of the element, which will make it appear over the top of the padding of the container. rather than having the image appear with a huge padding below it. See this example without the `position:absolute;`

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom:56.25%;
  background: black;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

To clarify the `transform`, it's there offset the `top:50%` of the image, because the default origin of elements is the top left pixel. So we use the `translateY(-50%)` to move the origin to the middle of the image so the `top: 50%` is actually calculated from the middle of the image.

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, could you clarify on what `position: absolute` and `transform` are doing in the second example? And why `width: 80%;` and `overflow: hidden;` in the second example?

Comment: The image is being shown bigger than the black background and overflowing.  I have a `<div>` with `  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; display: flex-item;
  flex: 0 1 50%;` as the parent of the container. Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: Just checking in to see if you've seen my previous comment. Please let me know.